# Linux: use find to find text files?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, shell, find

Is there a way to specify to `find` that I only want text files (and not binary files)? `Grep` has an option to exclude binary files, so I thought `find` probably has a similar feature, but I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `grep` looks at the file's contents.

```
find . -exec sh -c "file -b --mime-type {} | grep -q '^text/'" \; -print
```

Comment: In Ubuntu this is `find . -exec sh -c "file -b --mime {} | grep -q '^text/'" \; -print`

Answer (score 4):

`find` can find files by their metadata, but not check contents. However, you can couple it with `file`:

```
find .git -type f -exec file -iN0 {} + |
awk -F '\0' '$2 ~ /^: text\// {print $1}'
```

(You can remove the `| awk ...` part if you also want more detailed information.)